# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '03/03/2020,03/03/2020' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have one form which contains "NO" and "Date". It will be Dynamic form. While doing a batch update in Spring Boot JPA i got the "java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '03/03/2020,03/03/2020' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10" exception

```
@RequestMapping(value="/abcpage", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public String savePurchaseEntries(@ModelAttribute ABC abc,HttpSession session)
{

    System.out.println(abc);
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.parse(abc.getDate(),dateTimeFormatter);
    abc.setLoclaDate(today);
    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

Here ABC is the entity class and i can get the date value in dd/mm/yyyy format and convert into localdate and set into the entity.

```
ABC[NO=101,102,date=03/03/2020,03/03/2020]
```

for one entry it is working fine but while batch it throw the exception.

```
@Entity
class ABC{ 
@column(name="NO") 
private String NO;
@Transient
private String date;
@Column(name="invdate")
private LocalDate loclaDate;
//getters & setters//tostring
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem with your code, if I understood your input correctly, is that you're passing comma(,) separated date strings in `LocalDate.parse(abc.getDate(),dateTimeFormatter)`.

You need to pass a single date each time to parse() method as it tries to format the provided string input with that of date formatter format and hence error occurs when it encounters comma(,) in input of "03/03/2020,03/03/2020".

Please refer to [official documentation for same.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-)

Below is something you can try :

```
String[] inputDates = abc.getDate().split[","];
for (String date : inputDates) {
 // you can now use LocalDate.parse(abc.getDate(),dateTimeFormatter) here
 // write your logic here.
}
```

I hope this helps you get your doubt cleared, if not let me know your exact question and I will try to help you out.

**EDIT 1** For inserting data

Below is a way in which you can insert data,

Create a table which will store dates having 3 columns - id(P.K.), abc_id(F.K. ref. of ABC table), date (store single date here).
Now let's say name of above table is abc_date_map, then reference this entity as OneToMany in your ABC entity. Like below,

```
@Entity
class ABC { 

 @Column(name="NO") 
 private String NO;

 @Transient
 private String date;

 @Column(name="abc_date_map_id")
 private List<AbcDateMap> abcDateMapEntityList;

 //getters & setters//tostring

}
```

And your AbcDateMap entity will be like

```
@Entity
public class AbcDateMap{

 @Column(name="abc_id")
 private Integer abcId;

 @Column(name="date")
 private LocalDate localDate;

 // getters setters
 
}
```

And your entity insertion logic will be like :

```
public Long insert(ABC abc) {

 abc.setNo(/*something*/);
 
 List<AbcDateMap> l = new ArrayList<>();
 
 AbcDateMap abcDate = new AbcDateMap();
 for (String date : abc.getDate().split(",")) {
  abcDate.setLocalDate(/*parse date here and store*/);
  abcDate.setAbcId(abc.getId());
 }
 abc.setAbcDateMapEntityList(l);
 repo.save(abc);

}
```

Now above is not exact code, you will have to polish it out, might have syntax/semantics mistakes. Also you will need to change it according to your requirements.

Comment: Thank you @prashantdoshi28:) This issue has been resolved, but in db it stored in a single entry 

Example:
101,102     03-03-2020

i need seperate entries.

Batch insert is not happend.

Comment: @V.Monisha ok, so problem is batch insert is not happening?

Comment: Yes @prashantdoshi28

Comment: @V.Monisha Ok, so correct me if i'm wrong in understanding this. You have to store entity of type ABC in db which has multiple Dates in column "invdate"?

Comment: I have to insert bulk data in single shot not only invdate.

Comment: Hi @V.Monisha please check edited answer. Hope it helps, if not, let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your update.... if possible there is way for batch update like in jdbc?

Comment: Hi, I have problem with Ajax side. I changed the details instead of [NO=101,102, date=03/03/2020,03/03/2020] I have sent 0: {NO=101, date=03/03/2020}, 1: {NO=102, date=03/03/2020}
Then on controller I have iterated those elements and saved it.